# Create-next-app generating typescript project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to generate a nextJs project in javascript, but when I run this command `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss ./`, it generates a typescript project.

Anyone, please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't do what you want you can create an next app : `create npx create-next-app my-tailwind-app` and then install [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Found [here all the process](https://dev.to/davidhayes/setting-up-tailwind-css-with-next-js-h67) to create next app with tailwind